# Deployed Angular SPA Application with .Net backend on Windows Server 2019

Tags: angular, deployment, .net-7.0, windows-server-2019

I have created application using command `dotnet new angular` in terminal. As I understand this is type of application is called "Angular SPA (Single Page Application) with .NET backend".

I have deployed application on Windows Server 2019,IIS and I have installed all necessary tools.

Visually application works perfectly (Fron-side) ,but I have issues with the Back-end. I think it's not running.

How can I test the deployed or find out if it's running or not ?

I have published the whole application using command dotnet publish -c Release -o d:\Somewhere (Please tell if I should do it in any other way).